# Python html browsing Local url path issue

Tags: python, html, directory, path

I use python to generate html pages. Under root folder I create two folders A and B. In B there are b1.html, b2.html, and so on. In folder A, I have A1.html and A2.html and so on. In A1.html, when generating such html, I create links to bx.html based on the keyword bx occurring in A1.html.

For example:

```
    stringsCounterNames = re.findall('\[([A-Z].*?)\]',line) #find the keywords
    stringsCounterNames = list(dict.fromkeys(stringsCounterNames)) #remove duplicates
    counter_path="B_Folder"
    if (len(stringsCounterName)>0):

        for stringCounter in stringsCounterNames:
            targetStr=counter_dic[stringCounter]
            target = '<a href="' + counter_path + '/' + targetStr + '.html">' + stringCounter + '<a>'
            line = re.sub(stringCounter, target, line)
            print(line)
```

In above code, it will create a link like this:
`<a href="B_Folder/b1.html">stringCounter</a>`
So the problem is when browsing A1.html, clicking the link, it goes to: `File:rootFolder/A_Folder/B_Folder/b1.html`, so the link never works as both A_Folder and B_Folder are child folder under rootFolder.
I can move B_Folder under A_Folder to solve the issue, but I want to make files organized. Is there a way to fix this easily? I tried changing "counter_path" to "..B_Folder" or ".B_Folder", never works. I can't put absolute path to it as it will be migrate to some other root folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative path `counter_path="../B_Folder"` should work.

Your suggestions are close, but both `..B_Folder` and `.B_Folder` are valid folder names; therefore, the relative path would still be `root/A_Folder/..B_Folder` or `root/A_Folder/.B_Folder`. However, the folder names `..` and `.` refer to the parent folder and the current folder, respectively. Adding `..` as a separate folder (therefore changing the path to `root/A_Folder/../B_Folder`) works: from `root/A_Folder`, navigating to `..` changes the path to `root`, from which you can navigate to `B_Folder`.

For more examples with `.` and `..`, see [this answer to a Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249041).